# useParams getting 0 in console log but correct id in url while I am trying to edit in my curd react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { getItemById } from '../actions';

const About = ({ toEdit, getItemById }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const { id } = useParams();
    const userId = id;
    console.log('id from url ' + userId);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(toEdit);
        const findById = toEdit.find((element) => element.id === parseInt(userId));
        console.log(findById);

         const user = toEdit.find((element) => {
            console.log(element.id + "    " + parseInt(userId) + " url id" );
            if (element.id === parseInt(id))
                return element
         })
        
        console.log(user);

    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        toEdit: state.items
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItemById })(About);
```

The problem is the state is getting updated with recent item added but useParams cannot access the recently added id from url and its showing zero can be seen in snippet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEyqt.png)
Image showing console log of the issue useParam id is getting zero for newly added task
while trying to edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you parse `"0.2847260858902325"` to an integer the result will be `0`.

Use `parseFloat` or `Number` instead.

```js
const element = { id : 1234 };
const userId = "0.2847260858902325";

console.log(element.id + "    " + parseInt(userId) + " url id" );
console.log(element.id + "    " + parseFloat(userId) + " url id" );
console.log(element.id + "    " + Number(userId) + " url id" );
```

Or since the issue stems from the element id being a number type and the match params being a string type and you are using strict equality (`===`) an alternative would be to use loose equality (`==`) in which Javascript will attempt to coerce types.

```
const user = toEdit.find((element) => {
  console.log(element.id + "    " + parseInt(userId) + " url id" );
  return element.id == id; // will coerce types
})
```

```js
console.log("0.2847260858902325" === 0.2847260858902325); // false
console.log("0.2847260858902325" == 0.2847260858902325);  // true
```

See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for detailed differences between "==" and "===".